# Hide and unhide folders

Tags: directory, minecraft, hidden-files

is there any way to unhide folders other than removing the "." in fornt of it. becasue i have minecraft and the folder which you install mods to is called ".minecraft" and its in /home/usr but i want to unhide it but the name of it has to be ".minecraft" (its called that on all os) is there any way to unhide it but keep the name of ".minecraft"?
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 12):

Pressing control-H in Nautilus will show also files starting with a `.`.

[image]

If you want this permanent: Files > Preferences will have a setting for this:

[image]

In command line `ls -la` the `a` part will also show hidden files.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't like to show all hidden files all the time, then you can make a link to the folder you wish to unhide.

- Go to the folder you wish to unhide. (.minecraft)
- If necessary unhide it by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>H</kbd>.
- Right-click it an choose "Make Link".
- You now have a link to the folder that you can rename and place wherever you like.